# Webdriverjs no sleep statements stale element reference

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the following block of code that uses action sequences to perform the following:

- click on a link to a page
- wait for an input field on the page to appear
- click the input field
- delete any text that exists
- send a sequence of keys to enter a location
- hit the down arrow (the input uses autcomplete)
- hit the enter key to select the correct location
- click the save button

I have read that using `driver.sleep()` statements is not recommended but I can't get the the code to work properly without them.

Here is the code block:

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("a[href*='details/location']")), 5000)
driver.findElement(By.css("a[href*='details/location']")).click()
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id("user_location")), 5000)
let loc = driver.findElement(By.id("user_location"))
let save = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Save')]"))
driver.sleep(3000)
driver.actions().
    click(loc).
    sendKeys(Key.DELETE)
    .sendKeys('My location')
    .perform()
driver.sleep(1000)
driver.actions().
    sendKeys(Key.ARROW_DOWN).
    sendKeys(Key.ENTER).
    perform()
driver.sleep(1000)
driver.actions().
    click(save).
    perform()
```

Is there a better way to go about doing this and/or is there a way to remove the sleep statements?  Why exactly do the `stale element` errors happen when I pul out the sleep statements?

Answer (score 0):

One issue may be the time between scraping the page for `loc` and `save` and actually using them. Try rearranging the code as below and see if that helps.

Another thing I noticed, `driver.wait()` returns the element waited on so you can combine lines 1 & 2 and lines 3 & 4 so you don't have to scrape twice.

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("a[href*='details/location']")), 5000).click()
let loc = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id("user_location")), 5000)
# driver.sleep(3000) # you shouldn't need this sleep?
driver.actions()
    .click(loc)
    .sendKeys(Key.DELETE)
    .sendKeys('My location')
    .perform()
driver.sleep(1000)
driver.actions()
    .sendKeys(Key.ARROW_DOWN)
    .sendKeys(Key.ENTER)
    .perform()
driver.sleep(1000)
let save = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Save')]"))
driver.actions()
    .click(save)
    .perform()
```

Comment: Same result with your code (although it's much cleaner).  If I don't use the first `driver.sleep(3000)` the autocomplete text doesn't populate correctly for whatever reason.  I want to get away from the sleep statements altogether but I can't seem to get things working without them.

Comment: You should try to figure out what the sleep is accomplishing. In the first case, can you detect that the autocomplete text is populating? Is it displayed in HTML?

Comment: Unfortunately I am having a hard time figuring out how to detect the auto completion because the options aren't dusplayed in the DOM.

Comment: On which line are you getting the stale element exception?

Comment: Using the code you provided, it happens at the second action sequence where I try to arrow down and then press enter (with the sleep statements commented out).

Comment: Is there some reason you are using `actions()` and then `.sendKeys()` instead of just using the generic `element.sendKeys()`? I'm guessing that's your problem. That second group of actions is probably pointed at the `loc` element which updated after the first action. Refetch the `loc` element and use `.sendKeys()` on it for the second action and see if that helps.

Comment: It looks like the autcomplete suggestions don't populate unless the `actions()` function is used.

Comment: I might have something.  I found the autocomplete items in the DOM so I am going to see if I can use that.